# How do you specify multiple Sort fields with Solrj?

Tags: solrj, solr4

I have an application using solr that needs to be able to sort on two fields. The Solrj api is a little confusing, providing multiple different APIs.
I am using Solr 4.10.4

I have tried:

```
           for (int i = 0; i < entry.getValue().size();) {
               logger.debug("Solr({}) {}: {} {}", epName, entry.getKey(), entry
                        .getValue().get(i), entry.getValue().get(i + 1));
              if (i == 0) {
                   query.setSort(new SolrQuery.SortClause(entry.getValue().get(i++), SolrQuery.ORDER.valueOf(entry.getValue().get(i++))));
               } else {
                   query.addSort(new SolrQuery.SortClause(entry.getValue().get(i++), SolrQuery.ORDER.valueOf(entry.getValue().get(i++))));
               }
             }
```

When I look at the generated URL I only see the last SortClause sort=sequence+asc

I also tried creating a List and the setSorts SolrQuery method and that too seems to output only as single sort field, always the last one.

I was able to create the correct sort clause by generating it manually with strings.

I have tried addOrUpdateSort as well.  I think I've tried most of the obvious combinations. of methods in the Solrj API.

This does work:

```
            StringBuilder sortString = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < entry.getValue().size();) {
                if (sortString.length() > 0) {
                    sortString.append(",");
                }
               logger.debug("Solr({}) {}: {} {}", epName, entry.getKey(), entry
                        .getValue().get(i), entry.getValue().get(i + 1));
               sortString.append(entry.getValue().get(i++)).append(" ").
                  append(SolrQuery.ORDER.valueOf(entry.getValue().get(i++)));
             }
            query.set("sort",sortString.toString());
```

The sort clause I want to see is: sort=is_cited+asc,sequence+asc
The solrj API seems to only output the final clause.
I suspect a bug in solrj 4.10

Answer (score 0):

can you substitute setSort with addSort ie

```
       for (int i = 0; i < entry.getValue().size();) {
           logger.debug("Solr({}) {}: {} {}", epName, entry.getKey(), entry
                    .getValue().get(i), entry.getValue().get(i + 1));
          if (i == 0) {
               query.addSort(new SolrQuery.SortClause(entry.getValue().get(i++), SolrQuery.ORDER.valueOf(entry.getValue().get(i++))));
           } else {
               query.addSort(new SolrQuery.SortClause(entry.getValue().get(i++), SolrQuery.ORDER.valueOf(entry.getValue().get(i++))));
           }
         }
```

And let me know if this worked

Comment: Tried that, didn't work. I tried every permutation I could think of. Only explicitly creating the parameter seemed to work.

Comment: Are you sure that you want to do this                    query.addSort(new SolrQuery.SortClause(entry.getValue().get(i++), SolrQuery.ORDER.valueOf(entry.getValue().get(i++))));
 and not this                    query.addSort(new SolrQuery.SortClause(entry.getValue().get(i), SolrQuery.ORDER.valueOf(entry.getValue().get(i)))); is the expression new SolrQuery.SortClause(entry.getValue().get(i++), SolrQuery.ORDER.valueOf(entry.getValue().get(i++))) evaluated correctly in both times (one for i=0 and for i>0)

Comment: The code is supposed to handle an arbitrary number of fields. It does too, solrj just throws away all but the last one. I also tried the API that uses a List<SolrQuery.SortClause> which I passed to the setSorts method. You'd think that a method that takes a list would do the right thing. It threw away all but the last SortClause too.

Answer (score 0):

Check out addOrUpdateSort()

```
Updates or adds a single sort field specification to the current sort
information. If the sort field already exist in the sort information map,
its position is unchanged and the sort order is set; if it does not exist,
it is appended at the end with the specified order..

@return the modified SolrQuery object, for easy chaining
@since 4.2
```